# Dynamic UITableViewCell Height with Exceptions

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to dynamically set the height of my custom cell. I used the below code and it works.

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = view.frame.height / 4
```

However, I need my table view at index 0 (first cell) as a header with a fixed height and the rest of the cells to have dynamic height.

I tried this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return (self.view.frame.height/2)
    }
    return tableView.estimatedRowHeight
}
```

But that just sets the height to whatever I set estimatedRowHeight to in the viewDidLoad()

How can I make it so that the first row at index 0 has a height of 1/2 of the screen

```
view.frame.height / 2
```

while the rest of the cells changes height dynamically. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to return `tableView.rowHeight` instead of `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` from `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method for the cells whose indexPaths are greater than 0:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  if indexPath.row == 0 {
    return (self.view.frame.height / 2)
  }
  return tableView.rowHeight // or return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ozgur gave me the hint I needed to figure it out.

instead of setting tableView.row height in the viewDidLoad(), I moved it to the cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    tableView.rowHeight = view.frame.height / 2

    ...

    return cell
} else {

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = view.frame.height / 4

    ...

    return cell
}
```

EDIT: Never mind. This actually doesn't work because the first cell is at index 0 and when it tries to create that cell the tableView set ALL the row heights to view.frame.height / 2